# Localised calendar in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, localization

I need to be able to display a calendar in localised form. This is not just linguistically, but also supporting non-Gregorian calendars. For example Persian, Chinese or Buddhist.

Previously, when I was working with Java I used [ICU4J](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/Calendar.html) for this, but I wasn't able to see how to approach this in NodeJS or browser based Javascript.

Can anyone suggest how I could do this? For example, if I needed to do something like:

```
const date = new Date();
console.log(formatDate('persian', date));
```

Comment: Do you mean this: [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat)?

Comment: From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): ***Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.***

Comment: @zero298 that work well for me. If you can expand on this with an example, it would make for a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method to convert calendars from one format to another. This method uses the upcoming Javascript's Temporal API (currently at Stage 3 TC39).

```html
<script type='module'>
// ====== load Temporray polyfill (not needed after full Temporal implementation) ========
import * as TemporalModule from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@js-temporal/polyfill@0.3.0/dist/index.umd.js'
//=====================================================================

// Y,M,D are the date to convert from
// options as in Intl.DateTimeFormat() with additional 'from' and 'locale'
// 'from': calendar name to convert from
// 'locale' the locale to use (default 'en')
// 'calendar': calendar to convert to
// All other options as in Intl.DateTimeFormat()
//---------------------------------------
function dateToCalendars(Y, M, D, op={}) {
return new Intl.DateTimeFormat(op.locale??="en",op).format(new Date(temporal.Temporal.PlainDateTime.from({year:Y,month:M,day:D,calendar:op.from??= "gregory"}).toString().split("[")[0]));
}
//---------------------------------------

//===============================
// Example Test Cases
//===============================

console.log(dateToCalendars(2022,2,25));     // default Gregory

// full format Gregory
console.log(dateToCalendars(2022,2,25, {dateStyle: "full"}));    

// from Persian to Gregory in full format
console.log(dateToCalendars(1400,12,6,{from: 'persian', dateStyle: "full"})); 

// from Persian to Gregory in full format in 'fa' locale
console.log(dateToCalendars(1400,12,6,{from: 'persian', dateStyle: "full", locale: "fa"}));

// from Persian to Islamic in full format in 'fa' locale
console.log(dateToCalendars(1400,12,6,{from: 'persian', calendar: 'islamic', dateStyle:"full", locale: "fa"})); 

// from Islamic to Gregory full format (default 'en' locale)
console.log(dateToCalendars(1443,7,24,{from:"islamic", dateStyle:"full"}));  

// from buddhist to Persian full format (default 'en' locale)
console.log(dateToCalendars(2745,3,11, {from:"buddhist", calendar: 'persian', dateStyle:"full"})); 

</script>
```